# Use a variable in another one declared within the same EnvironmentFile in systemd unit file

Tags: systemd

I have a rather long set of arguments to pass to an executable. I created a simple `systemd` unit file and it works well:

```
[Unit]
Description=My Service

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/opt/my-service
EnvironmentFile=-/opt/my-service/environment
ExecStart=/usr/bin/java $JAVA_ARGS -jar /opt/my-service/my-service.jar

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

In `/opt/my-service/environment`, I have the following (just an example):

```
JAVA_ARGS=-server -Xms1500m -Xmx1500m -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:NewRatio=1 -XX:SurvivorRatio=4 -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/my-service/tmp
```

I would like to be able to break down this variable into several to make it slightly more understandable. Something like that:

```
JAVA_TMP_DIR=/opt/my-service/tmp
JAVA_JVM_ARGS=-server -Xms1500m -Xmx1500m -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:NewRatio=1 -XX:SurvivorRatio=4
JAVA_ARGS=$JAVA_JVM_ARGS -Djava.io.tmpdir=$JAVA_TMP_DIR
```

But when I use that, the values of `$JAVA_JVM_ARGS` and `$JAVA_TMP_DIR` are not substituted and are printed as-is in `$JAVA_ARGS` (that is properly substituted):

```
[root@ip-10-0-1-140 system]# systemctl status my-service
my-service.service - My Service
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/my-service.service; enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2016-01-14 11:01:05 UTC; 3s ago
  Process: 28148 ExecStart=/usr/bin/java $JAVA_ARGS -jar /opt/my-service/my-service.jar (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 28148 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jan 14 11:01:05 ip-10-0-1-140.us-west-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Started My Service.
Jan 14 11:01:05 ip-10-0-1-140.us-west-1.compute.internal java[28148]: Error: Could not find or load main class $JAVA_JVM_ARGS
Jan 14 11:01:05 ip-10-0-1-140.us-west-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: my-service.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jan 14 11:01:05 ip-10-0-1-140.us-west-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Unit my-service.service entered failed state.
```

Is there any way to achieve such behaviour using environment files?

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** Just found a different solution:
If you have this

```
JAVA_TMP_DIR=/opt/my-service/tmp
JAVA_JVM_ARGS=-server -Xms1500m -Xmx1500m ... 
...
```

then you could set the ExecStart like this

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/java $JAVA_JVM_ARGS -Djava.io.tmpdir=${JAVA_TMP_DIR} -jar /opt/my-service/my-service.jar
```

(make sure the second variable is in { } )

**Below my original post, probably also a solution for someone:**

Actually it seems not to work, if you have an variable within the parameter like `-Djava.io.tmpdir=$JAVA_TMP_DIR`

I would suggest you to solve your problem like that. Change your EnvironmentFile like this:

```
JAVA_TMP_DIR='-Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/my-service/tmp'
```

Then you could change the unit file start up line to this:

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/java $JAVA_JVM_ARGS $JAVA_TMP_DIR -jar /opt/my-service/my-service.jar
```

This worked in my case.